# An unexpected error has occurred in SharePoint 2013 WebPart

Tags: sharepoint-server

When I click on date picker icon in Date filter, date picker pop up not shown.
[image: Error screen shot]

Comment: And if you click "TECHNICAL DETAILS" link and copy the Id and search for it in the ULS Log, what error do you see there?

Comment: @BennySkogberg i got this message
 Topology cache updated. (AppDomain: /LM/W3SVC/16727717/ROOT-1-131136257086910015)

Comment: This error occurred in new web application date filter web part.

Comment: Tough one. Have you added CacheSuperUser and CacheSuperReader to the Web Application?

Comment: Sorry, I could not find them to add to the web application

Answer (score 1):

ok, finally i got a answer for this question. 
We have to create a root site collection for that web application from central administration then datepicker popup works.